# Data encoding in Objective-C and Ruby

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ruby, nsstring

I'm working on an iOS app using Parse, and I need to simulate their encryption flow using Ruby for the website and browser extensions I'm building for it.

For generating the salt for `AES`, they have the following code in the iOS app:

```
NSString *str            =    user.email;
NSData *strData          =    [str dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData    =    [strData AESEncryptWithPassphrase:str]; // using the same key
```

What's puzzling me is dataUsingEncoding: `NSUTF8StringEncoding` -- it's obviously encoding the string in UTF-8, but when I see it in NSLog it seems quite different. So if str was "randomemail@gmail.com", doing `NSLog` on strData outputs:

<72616e64 6f6d656d 61696c40 676d6169 6c2e636f 6d>

Now, how do I get that same output in Ruby? I can't get the right salt because of this ("randomemail@gmail.com".encode("UTF-8") simply returns the email as expected). How can I simulate dataUsingEncoding in Ruby to get the same exact salt, is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
"randomemail@gmail.com".encode("UTF-8").bytes.to_a.map{ |x| x.to_s(16)}
```

and you will "see" what you want.

The hexadecimal representation of "randomemail@gmail.com" with UTF-8 encoding is

```
<72616e64 6f6d656d 61696c40 676d6169 6c2e636f 6d>
```

But ruby shows you the string representation, which is "randomemail@gmail.com".
They are showing the same stuff in different ways.

Check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) for more information.